# Python SQL statement with variables, using psycopg2 library

Tags: python, database, postgresql

```
 cur.execute('UPDATE newslib SET (keyword1) = %s WHERE id= %s' % m_k1,row[0])
```

I use `psycopg2` to execute this SQL statement.
`m_k1` and `row[0]` are two variables I want to pass into the statement.

This triggers the following error message:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I’ve been looking for solutions online, but I can’t fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the substitutions as arguments to `execute`. The way you have it written now you have specified two place holders, but did not provide their values, instead you are parsing them in the query itself.

```
cur.execute('UPDATE newslib SET (keyword1) = %s WHERE id= %s' , (m_k1,row[0],))
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the parameter as a sequence (instead of multiple individual values). And use `parameters` argument instead of formatting sql yourself.

```
cur.execute('UPDATE newslib SET (keyword1) = %s WHERE id= %s', [m_k1,row[0]])
#                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [`Cursor.execute`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14)